# sprite creation shapes not showing in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have unity 2019.4.28f1 and made a new 2d project. When I hover my mouse over sprites its not showing the basic shapes like square, capsule etc. I freshly installed this version of unity editor from the official website (not) the unity hub. [The Editor scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXEzz.png)

I was trying to add a square sprite in my scene

Comment: any reason you're using a 3+ year old version of unity? Is the error as you select the spirte from the menu or later?

Comment: I am using this version of unity because I have a very low end pc The newer versions are just very resource demanding

Comment: i paid <300 for a laptop and can run the current ones..